# How to make corners of buttons and field slightly rounder?

Tags: html, css

I got a mockup that I want to realize.

[image]

I have something that is almost good, but the corners of the buttons and the corners of the fields are not round enough:

[image]

Is it possible to apply the small rounding that is in the mockup? I got a fiddle with my result so far.

http://jsfiddle.net/niklasro/d4D8z/

```
body {
    font-family:'Raleway', sans-serif;
}
#element1 {display:inline-block;margin-left:10px; }

.textInput{padding-left:5px}

#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    height: 45px;
    border-bottom: solid 2px #0072c9;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 30;display:inline-block;
}
#header-title {
    left: 250px;
    font-size: 22px;
    bottom: 7px;
    color: #0072c9;
    font-weight: 400;
    position: absolute;
}
.title {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 23px;
    color: rgb(0, 114, 198);
    line-height: 1.429;
    z-index: 70;
}
#navigation-bar {
    width: 230px;
    height: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    z-index: 20;
    position: absolute;
}
#navigation-content {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 47px;
}
.navigation-button {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    margin: 15px 0px;
}
.navigation-header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    color: #0072c9;
    font-size: 25px;
}
.navigation-desc {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 15px;
    left: 10px;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #0072c9;
}

.login form {
    width: 445px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.login label {
    padding: 2px;
    display: block;
    line-height: 22px;
    background: #ebebeb;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-top: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.login label span {
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 10px;
}

.login label input {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 270px;
    height: 20px;
    float: right;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}
.login .buttons {
    margin-top: 7px;
    float: right;
}

.login .buttons button {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 33px;
    line-height:30px;
    background: rgb(0, 114, 198);
    color: white;
    font-size: 17px;
    border: none;
}
#upload-file {
    display:none;
}

#upload{
    display:none;
}
#logga {
    border-top: solid 2px #0072c9;
}
#logout {
    border-top: solid 2px #0072c9;
}
#navigation-content a:hover div.navigation-button {
    background:lightgrey;
}
#navigation-content a:hover div.navigation-button:before {
    content:' ';
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    right:-20px;
    top:15px;
    height:30px;
    width:30px;
    background:white;
    -webkit-transform-origin: 5px 25px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
}
table{  width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #00F;
    font-size:12px;}
th{background:#EEE;width:auto; text-align:center; padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #00F;}
td{width:auto; text-align:center; padding:5px 0;border:1px solid #00F;}
tr:nth-child(even) {background: #EEE;}
```

Comment: use __border-radius__.............. for more example and detail [visit](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) to you labels and buttons:

```
.login label {
     border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}

.login .buttons button {
     border-radius: 3px;
     -moz-border-radius: 3px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
}
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4D8z/3/)

Answer (score 1):

`border-radius` is used for rounded corners.

Write:

```
.login label{border-radius:5px;}
.login .buttons button{border-radius:3px;}
```

[**Updated fiddle here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/d4D8z/1/)

[More information here.](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-radius/)

Answer (score 0):

Use the **border-radius** css property

```
border-radius: 2px;
```

See: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_border-radius.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use border-radius property to get rounded corners.

```
.login label input {
    border-radius: 15px;
}
```

same can be applied to class .login label as well.

Answer (score 0):

`.login .buttons button {`
`border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;`
`-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;`
`}`
`.login label {border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;`
`-moz-border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;`
`}`

Try this.